# python password checker fails

Tags: python

I defined the following function to check the validity of a password, but it doesn't work for valid passwords. For a password to be valid, it should only have numbers and ascii letters, and must be longer than 10 chars. What I am I doing wrong?

```
def checker(password):
    letters = map(chr, range(97, 123))+ map(chr, range(65, 91))
    numbers = [range(0, 10)]
    if len(password) < 10:
            return 'Too short'
    for i in password:
        if (i not in letters or i not in numbers):
            return 'Password has invalid chars'
        return 'Password is valid'
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? You don't need to wrap `numbers` in a list, but other than that nothing looks _horribly wrong_ at first glance.

Comment: well the problem here is that a character like 'a' won't be in numbers

Answer (score 1):

fist your numbers is a nested list `range(0, 10)` is a list by itself you dont need to wrap in in a list ! and also you need to your numbers be string , so as a more efficient way you just could use `string` module for create your checking set Also you need to move your last `return` outside of `for` loop :

```
>>> s=string.ascii_letters+string.digits
>>> s
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
```

So your function could be like following :

```
def checker(password):
    s=string.ascii_letters+string.digits
    if len(password) < 10:
            return 'Too short'
    for i in password:
        if i not in s:
            return 'Password has invalid chars'
    return 'Password is valid'
```

Demo :

```
>>> checker('thisis4thtest')
'Password is valid'
>>> checker('thisis4thtest#')
'Password has invalid chars'
>>> checker('thisis4#')
'Too short'
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: the condition is wrong: `not in chars or not in numbers` is always true.

Second problem: your numbers are numbers (integers) and wrapped in another list, instead of just characters. Use `numbers = [str(x) for x in range(10)]`

Comment: it fails with invalid chars still even on "aaaaaaaaaa"

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker(password):
    letters = map(chr, range(97, 123))+ map(chr, range(65, 91))
    numbers = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
    if len(password) < 10:
            return 'Too short'
    for i in password:
        if not (i in letters or i in numbers):
            return 'Password has invalid chars'
        return 'Password is valid'
```

Your if logic was a bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find if password only contains ascii letters and numbers or not

```
import re
check = re.compile('^[\w]{10,}$')
if check.match(password):
    return 'Password is valid'
else:
    return 'Password has invalid chars'
```

Comment: Was just writing the same answer....  change that to `^[\w]{10,}$` to get the length requirement in there too.